# It seems like updates described in the KB3057134 make PowerShell to start slow

Tags: powershell

Starting this morning it takes 3-4 seconds to start even very simple PowerShell script on my machine. This command shows 3.2-3.4 seconds on my machine and only 0.4 second on co-worker's machine.

```
powershell ( Measure-Command { powershell "Write-Host 1" } ).TotalSeconds
```

I know there are thousands of possible reasons (including viruses!)... But I don't see any suspicious activity on my machine, and I've installed a bunch of Windows updates this morning, and it was the only significant change in my environment.

I'm wondering if anybody has the same problem.

Comment: Anything in your `$profile` which might load modules or perform other lengthy tasks?

Comment: "powershell -NoProfile ..." gives me the same results...

Comment: run a processmonitor and watch where you loose time, if loading something on disk in example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like updates described in the following KB article lead to the problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057134

I uninstalled these updates and the problem disappeared, I installed them again and the problem came back (tested both on Win 8.1/PS4 and Win 7/PS3).

Thank you all guys for your suggestions!

Comment: P.S. This problem on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1332211/

Answer (score 0):

I ran your command on my powershell & it took 3.21 seconds the first time. Second time & further ones took 0.65 seconds. I'm running ps 4.0. I've also had my console session opened for a few days. Do you and you co-worker run the same ps version? Same hardware? Have you tried the dreaded reboot?

Comment: Yes, we run the same version (3.0) and I've reboot my machine. I also tried other machines, including virtual machines. The virtual machine which is running on my computer and which was not updated recently show me 0.4 seconds for this command. And it seems like on these machines which were updated this morning this command runs significantly longer.

Comment: Do you re-run the command again in the same session to see if it's changed. I assume you have but just checking. Well you seem to think the updates might be the culprit. I haven't done updates today but you could try to uninstall the updates from today and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! It seems like I was able to identify the update which caused the problem.